# Rotas de authenticação não definidas, laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, auth

Não consigo fazer acessar a rota  http://localhost/login   diretamente e nem http://localhost/logout.

```
Route::get('/', function () {
        if(Auth::check()) {
            return redirect('/dashboard');
        } else {
            return view('auth.login');
        }
    });


    Auth::routes();

    Route::group([
            'prefix' => 'dashboard/admin',
            'as' => 'admin.',
            'middleware' => 'auth'
        ], function() {
        Route::resource('clientes', 'ClientsController');
        Route::resource('devedors', 'DevedorController');

        Route::post('titulos/upload', 'TituloController@uploadSubmit')->name('titulos.upload');
        Route::get('titulos/documents/{id}', 'TituloController@documents')->name('titulos.documents');
        Route::resource('titulos', 'TituloController');

        //Route::post('document/delete/{id}', 'DocumentController@delete')->name('document.delete');
        Route::resource('document', 'DocumentController');

    });




    Route::get('/dashboard', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

Comment: posta suas rotas, você implementou o ```php artisan make:auth ```

Comment: Eu postei aí acima!

Comment: tente isso em suas rotas https://gist.github.com/AndreMart/0508510dbf03354bddd8cf9653cbc41e